# Передача переменой из почты

Tags: php, email, global-variables

Доброго дня! У меня проблема с конструкцией в теле e-mail письма вида:

```
<img src="site.ru / send_done.php?sended='. $row['id'].'">
```

Здесь я передаю некое значение id данного адреса своему скрипту, благодаря чему могу отметить факт открытия письма получателем.

Это работает с почтой **мэйл.ру** и **гмэйл** точно!

Но яндекс почта почему то на отрез не хочет пересылать так переменную скрипту.

Есть ли какие соображения по этому поводу ?

Может, что-то не так с синтаксисом ?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Так делать очень плохо. Очень. А не работает, потому что картинки по умолчанию просто не открываются  - нормальная практика. gmail также не подгружает картинки, если решил, что это спам.

Comment: Дык gmail работает в этом случае же ... А почему плохо ?

Comment: гмейл отработал, потому что решил, что Ваше письмо не спам. А плохо - сами можете догадаться. Например, можете легко задосить себя

Comment: Про дос - это ясно .. но это самый рабочий метод, который я знаю на данный момент .. Да, есть еще нормальная валидация через сгенерированный код и прокликиванием от пользователя - но это по факту согласия самого клиента, Мне же важно понять, открывал ли он вообще письмо хотябы ...

Comment: Вы бы свое письмо в ящике от яндекса глянули, а то может там и нет ни какого img, так как их система защиты его турнула из тела письма.

Comment: А вот когда Вы задедоситесь, то у пользователя может даже письмо и не открыться (все зависит от конкретного клиента, но все же). Не нужно пытаться понять, открывал ли пользователь письмо. Для законных целей это не нужно. Пользователь мог просто открыть и пойти дальше. И также всякие AdBlocker'ы любят вырезать подобные ссылки

Comment: есть, но он "display: none" естественно... Также, каждый почтовик как-то по-своему кодирует мой код . но вот все (гугл, мэйл, рамблер) его отрабатываюит тем не менее, а яндекс не ....

Comment: Именно, тогда я и пойму, что он проигнорил мое письмо, открым его . значит этот товар ему не нужен и я буду думать, как подойти с более выгодной стороны ..

Comment: далеко не факт, что он проигнорировал письмо.

Comment: КоВадим, прошу прощения, но это уже уход в глубину вопроса .. сейчас меня волнует тот факт, что из всех почтовиков мое действие игнорит яндекс. ..

Comment: Если Вам это кажется неверным - напишите в службу поддержки Яндекса. Но я считаю, что яндекс делает все абсолютно правильно и законно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73774/discussion-between-bertalino-and-kovadim).

Comment: Я абсолютно так не считаю. Безусловно - это меры безопасности. Но почему же даже гугл не парится ) Да потомучто до него письмо доходит чуть ли не через минуту - пока он там все проверит )

Answer (score 0):

Cвязался с техподдержкой Яндекс - они извинились даже )) Причем, примерно в это же время переменная начала работать - я ничего не трогал двое суток ... Мистика